# Podman unable to mount local file into container

Tags: volume, mount, podman

I'm planning to move away from Docker to Podman.
I use docker-compose a lot so am planning to switch to podman-compose as well.

However I'm stuck at the simplest of podman examples, I can't seem to mount a volume onto my container? Obviously I'm doing something wrong however I cant figure out what it is.

My source file definitely exists on my (hardware) host (so not the podman machine). but I keep getting the error 'no such file or directory'.

Funny thing is if I manually create the same file locally on the podman machine (podman machine ssh --> touch /tmp/test.txt) it works perfectly fine.

Question is;

- should I (manually?) mount all my local files onto the Fedora VM (podman machine) so that in turn this Fedora mount can be used in my actual container? and if so, how do I do this?
- The `podman run` cmd below should work and there is something else I'm doing wrong?

```
$ ls -al /tmp/test.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 <username> <group> 10 Dec 8 13:33 /tmp/test.txt

$ podman run -it -v /tmp/test.txt:/tmp/test.txt docker.io/library/busybox
Error: statfs /tmp/test.txt: no such file or directory

$ podman run -it -v /tmp/test.txt:/tmp/test.txt:Z docker.io/library/busybox
Error: statfs /tmp/test.txt: no such file or directory
```

Additional information:

```
$ podman info --debug
host:
  arch: amd64
  buildahVersion: 1.23.1
  cgroupControllers:
  - memory
  - pids
  cgroupManager: systemd
  cgroupVersion: v2
  conmon:
    package: conmon-2.0.30-2.fc35.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.0.30, commit: '
  cpus: 10
  distribution:
    distribution: fedora
    variant: coreos
    version: "35"
  eventLogger: journald
  hostname: localhost.localdomain
  idMappings:
    gidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 65536
    uidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 65536
  kernel: 5.15.6-200.fc35.x86_64
  linkmode: dynamic
  logDriver: journald
  memFree: 11733594112
  memTotal: 12538863616
  ociRuntime:
    name: crun
    package: crun-1.3-1.fc35.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/crun
    version: |-
      crun version 1.3
      commit: 8e5757a4e68590326dafe8a8b1b4a584b10a1370
      spec: 1.0.0
      +SYSTEMD +SELINUX +APPARMOR +CAP +SECCOMP +EBPF +CRIU +YAJL
  os: linux
  remoteSocket:
    exists: true
    path: /run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: true
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: true
  serviceIsRemote: true
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    package: slirp4netns-1.1.12-2.fc35.x86_64
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.1.12
      commit: 7a104a101aa3278a2152351a082a6df71f57c9a3
      libslirp: 4.6.1
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 3
      libseccomp: 2.5.3
  swapFree: 0
  swapTotal: 0
  uptime: 7h 9m 29.12s (Approximately 0.29 days)
plugins:
  log:
  - k8s-file
  - none
  - journald
  network:
  - bridge
  - macvlan
  volume:
  - local
registries:
  search:
  - docker.io
store:
  configFile: /var/home/core/.config/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 4
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 4
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions: {}
  graphRoot: /var/home/core/.local/share/containers/storage
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: xfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "true"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  imageStore:
    number: 8
  runRoot: /run/user/1000/containers
  volumePath: /var/home/core/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 3.4.2
  Built: 1636748737
  BuiltTime: Fri Nov 12 20:25:37 2021
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.16.8
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 3.4.2
```

Comment: Maybe related to [Podman issue #8016 _Support native source folder for volume mount in remote model_](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/8016)? (just a guess)

Comment: @ErikSjölund thanks for the suggestion. this is exactly my issue. Four days ago an useful command was made. I'll add a post for other users.

Comment: *command=comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by @ErikSjölund there has been an active treat on https://github.com/containers/podman. Apparantely Centos (Podman Machine) does not (yet) support different types of volume creation on the machine.

It's not perse Podman lacking this feature it's waiting for CentOS to support this feature as well.

However, should you want to mount a local directory onto the machine I recommend have a look at https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/8016#issuecomment-995242552. It describes how to do a read-only mount on CoreOS (or break compatibility with local version).

Info:

https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/11454
https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/12584

Answer (score 0):

I also ran:

```
podman machine set --rootful podman-machine-default
```